# Missing data when joining tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am missing data when I select some "season" variables. The issue, I believe, is in the where clause. I use:

```
"where season = @season Or season IS NULL"
```

This allows me to get all the data from table a and match data from table b for a particular season. This works great for some seasons and not for others. For 2018 season, I get all rows from table a, which is what I want. But if i use 2019 season, it omits any records that do not have null values

My select command I am using is:

```
SELECT    a.customerid,
          a.lname,
          a.fname,
          b.customerid,
          b.mtg1,
          b.mtg2,
          b.mtg3,
          b.mtg4,
          (COALESCE(Sum(b.mtg1), 0) + COALESCE(Sum(b.mtg2), 0) + COALESCE(Sum(b.mtg3), 0) + COALESCE(Sum(b.mtg4), 0)) AS total
FROM      customer a
LEFT JOIN hours b
ON        a.customerid = b.customerid
WHERE     b.season = @Season
OR        b.season IS NULL
GROUP BY  a.customerid,
          a.lname,
          a.fname,
          b.customerid,
          b.mtg1,
          b.mtg2,
          b.mtg3,
          b.mtg4,
ORDER BY  a.lname
```

For example this is the data I have:

[image]

[image]

This is the data I get for 2019

[image]

But this is the data I want for 2019

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the `WHERE` clause in the `ON` clause (and you can omit the `OR` part):

```
...
LEFT JOIN hours b
ON        a.customerid = b.customerid
AND       b.season = @Season
...
```